# What is the meaning of あっています

Tags: meaning

I came across あっています in many places mostly in e-mail communication, but not able to get the exact meaning. I searched in jisho.org and found [あっています](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99) is same as ある but not giving　correct meaning for below example?

What is the correct meaning for below sentence?

> マネージャーという認識{にんしき}であっています

Comment: Check [あう](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%90%88%E3%81%86), not ある.

Comment: Yes you are right あう gives correct meaning. But I searched in jisho.com http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99 which gives ある, so got confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「合{あ}っています」 means "correct".

> "Your/Someone's understanding that someone is a manager is correct."